# How to create a function in SQL Server to compare 2 datetime2 values with GETDate and return a boolean

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, sql-function

I want to query a big table (more than 50k rows, +200 rows/day) with a where condition on a computed value.

In my table I have 2 columns which contains the Shift (1 or 2 or 3) and a date (like: 2019-07-29 00:00:00.000);

I want to select all rows from current shift.

I want to create a function which will calculate the shift start datetime and due datetime than will compare if the GETDATE() is in between, if true than will return the row.

I try to create this function:

```
Create function IsCurrentShift(@shift int,@shiftDate DateTime)
returns bit
as
Begin
    Declare @result DateTime2,
     @hours int,
     @shiftStartDate DateTime2,
     @shiftDueDate DateTime2

 set @hours =   (CASE 
    when @shift = 1 then 6
    when @shift = 2 then 14 
    when @shift = 3 then 22 
    else 6
    end)

 set @shiftStartDate = DATEADD(hour,@hours,@shiftDate)
 set @shiftDueDate=DATEADD(hour,8,@shiftStartDate)

 if @shiftStartDate < GETDATE() and @shiftDueDate > GETDATE()
        set @result = 1
 else 
        set @result = 0

    Return @result
End
```

Obviously is not running (I have no clue how to fixed).

The error is:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure IsCurrentShift, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with datetime2
>
> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure IsCurrentShift, Line 24 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with datetime2

This function I want to call it like this:

```
Select * 
From tbl 
Where IsCurrentShift(shift, date) = 1;
```

I have 2 questions:

1. There is a better approach to filter my table? for getting current productionOrders?
2. Can you help me fix this function?

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductionOrders]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ShiftNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

I want to use this function in a view.

Comment: I found mistake here @result DateTime2, still remain the question if there is a better way?

Comment: Do you *really* need a function for this? Multi-line scalar functions can run pretty slowly. What you have *could* be inlined, but not in 2014 (as inline scalar functions aren't supported). If you *must* use a function, you'd be better off with an inline table value function.

Comment: @Larnu No I do not really want a function, I was thinking that this way my query will be more readable. I try to improve performance of my app by creating some Views , I do not have sql experience. I am open to better solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalar functions are best avoided unless you are on SQL Server 2019, and even then...

You can write this direct into your query, or you can create an inline table-valued function to do it (much more performant than a scalar function).

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION IsCurrentShift
    (@shift int, @shiftDate DateTime)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
(SELECT
    Result = CASE WHEN v2.shiftStartDate < GETDATE() and v2.shiftDueDate > GETDATE()
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM (SELECT hours = 
        CASE 
        when @shift = 1 then 6
        when @shift = 2 then 14 
        when @shift = 3 then 22 
        else 6
        end,
        ) v1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT
        shiftStartDate = DATEADD(hour, v1.hours, @shiftDate),
        shiftDueDate =   DATEADD(hour,8 + v1.hours, @shiftDate)
    ) v2;
```

A table-valued function logically returns a whole table each time it gets called (in practice it is inlined, so much faster). In this case we are only returning a single calculated row. So you can either use it in a correlated subquery, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE (SELECT Result FROM IsCurrentShift(shift,date)) = 1;
```

Or you can also `APPLY` the result. This gives you a new column in your resultset:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
CROSS APPLY IsCurrentShift(shift,date) IsCurrent
WHERE IsCurrent.Result = 1;
```

You could also change the function to actually return shift start and end times.

Comment: I understand your point, but I do not get it, how to use this inline w/o creating the function?. I have very basic knowledge of sql

Comment: Now its clear, I will create the function which return a table not a scalar.

Comment: Have clarified it

Comment: @marc_s I don't think you're right, for the vast majority of cases in the wild it is a bad idea. Aaron Bertrand has [a good write-up](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5864/four-ways-to-improve-scalar-function-performance-in-sql-server/) proving this even on a non-data function, and Brent Ozar also [shows](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/forced-serialization/) how it forces a serial plan. Encapsulation can be done with an iTVF as I have shown.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the current shift number:

```
hour(dateadd(hour, -6, getdate())) / 8 + 1
```

Adjust backward six hours (because shift 1 starts at 6am.) Extract the hour and integer divide by eight (all shifts are equal length.)

Comment: yes, this is a good way to get the current shift (just divide by 8),